# tab size is not setting properly

Tags: html, asp.net, css, ajax

I'm using ajax tab control my code is given below-

```
 .mar
        { 
            margin-left: 100px;            
        }

        .siz
        {
            font-size: 200%;
            height: 68px;
            width: 171px;
        }
 <div class="mar">                  
                <ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
                    Width="1119px" Height="422px">
                    <ajax:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <div class="siz">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Home</div>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                    </ajax:TabPanel>
```

[image: I'm trying to solve this -]

Please see the image and suggest me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where do you apply siz class ?

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Height - sets the height of the body of the tabs (does not include the TabPanel headers)

try and change it.

see this link for further reference
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/11/ajax-tabcontainer-sample-or-how-to.html